# Filehelper differenciate errors based on Exception Message and manipulate record string

Tags: c#, linq, filehelpers

I am using the FileHelpers library for identifying errors in processing csv file.

```
var engine = new DelimitedFileEngine<ModelClass>;
        engine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;
        List<object> fileEngineResult = engine.ReadFile(fullFileName).ToList();
errorInfo = engine.ErrorManager.Errors;
```

My ModelClass has the properties corresponding to each column in my csv file with validation attributes

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines]

public class ModelClass
{
    [FieldNotEmpty]
    private string column1;       

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "MM/dd/yyyy")]
    private DateTime datecolumn;

    [FieldNotEmpty]
    private string column3;
}
```

1. Now for me  any error in the field not empty is critical hence I will have to deal with seperately.
2. For a non critical error, in this case datecolumn, I need to replace wrong value with null.

I could achieve my 1st requirement using the below code( it is still a crude way)

```
 List<object> criticalErrorList = new List<object>();
List<object> softErrorList = new List<object>();
foreach (var error in errorInfo)
        {
if (error.ExceptionInfo.InnerException.ToString().Contains("The value is empty and must be populated"))
            {
                criticalErrorList.Add(error);
            }
            else
            {  error.RecordString = //replace recordstring for the error column with null;
                softErrorList.Add(error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea to achieve 2nd requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question more carefully I see that want you really want is to get a null value when there is an error in your datecolum field.

I wrote this answer first and I'll let it here because I think you can benefit from it too. Maybe you could get a null value if field is missing and also get a null value if field data is wrong.

> **Initial answer (handling missing values with nullable types.)**

Fortunately you don't need to change the record string (it's readonly), but you use something [built-in](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/MissingValues/MissingValuesNullable/) in FileHelpers to achieve that. Change your model so the date column is a nullable DateTime.

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "MM/dd/yyyy")]
private DateTime? datecolumn;
```

Another approach is if you would want to have a default value for the date column. Then you could use another attribute to decorate the datecolumn member:

```
[FieldNullValue(typeof(DateTime), "01/01/1900")]
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "MM/dd/yyyy")]
private DateTime datecolumn;
```

> **Updated answer:**

**Get null value when data is wrong**

*Converters:*
This is another feature of FileHelpers. You can read more about it [here](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Converters/CustomConverter/):

So, let say you need to get a null value if the data is wrong for date column. You'll still need to change your datecolumn field to DateTime? but also you'll need a converter.

```
public class DateConverter : ConverterBase
    {
        public override object StringToField(string from)
        {
            //if you can't convert to date time.. .return null
            DateTime date;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(from, out date))
                return null;

            return date;
        }

        public override string FieldToString(object fieldValue)
        {
            return ((DateTime) fieldValue).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy").Replace(".", "");
        }
    }
```

And in your model class, decorate the field with the converter:

```
[FieldConverter(typeof(DateConverter))]
public DateTime? datecolumn;
```

Now you'll get no erros when reading the file and if the date field is wrong in the file, you'll get a null value in the model class.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, the options you have given are good. But I also want to capture the error to log it, and also want the record will null value. Plus these soft errors can come for int, Say i expect a int but string is passed. Any thoughts ? I will defintely try out the solution you have given