# Filehelper - Raise error even if FieldConverter is used

Tags: c#, filehelpers

This is a continuation to the question
[Manipulate Error Record in FileHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663351/filehelper-differenciate-errors-based-on-exception-message-and-manipulate-record)

I have got to know that if there is an error, we can override it using null value as answered in the above question.

If I override the value, the fact that there was an error in the 1st place is lost. Is there a way to update wrong value with null and also throw error in the erroinfo for that record?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store the errors somewhere yourself and throw them after the rows have been processed.

```
public class DateConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        //if you can't convert to date time.. .return null
        DateTime date;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(from, out date))
        {
            ErrorTracker.Add(string.Format("Failed to parse date {0}.", from));
            return null;
        }

        return date;
    }
    /// etc...
}

public static class ErrorTracker
{
    public static List<string> ErrorList = new List<string>();
    public static void Add(string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorList.Add(errorMessage);
    }
    public static void Clear()
    {
        ErrorList.Clear();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ModelClass>();
        ErrorTracker.Clear();
        var productRecords = engine.ReadFile(@"C:\whatever.txt");
        foreach (var errorMessage in ErrorTracker.ErrorList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```